# Crystal Report- Show last page

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I've a crystal report inside my application. My report has about 100 pages. I need to see last page as soon as I open my report from my application.

So I'm using `crystalreportviewer.showlastpage`.

My report says page 100 on the top, but  it shows page 1 of 100.
if I press enter on the top box besides 100, it shows page 100 of 100.
Please help me in fixing this.

I need to see page 100 of 100 directly.

I shouldn't use lastpage button on the top as part of my requirement

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the showlastpage method when the form loads?  Does it work if called from a button (outside the crystalreportviewer control)? If so, you might need to delay calling the method until after the form is loaded (try threading or a timer).

Comment: I'm not calling showlastpage method on form load. I have a method which I has all the parameters that needs to be passed to the report.

Comment: Got it to working. I did not notice that method is being called at the begining of form load. Now I'm calling it at the end of form load.It's working. Thank you. I appreciate your help